# Bitwise operators in c++ and overloading

Tags: c++

I have written some code to print the value of an integer raised to an integer power.
Why does this code pause for input even after I have entered 2 integers?

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    int a, b;
    std::cin>>a>>b;
    std::cout<<std::endl<<a<<std::endl<<b<<std::endl;
    int c, d;
    c = a;
    d = 0;
    while(b){
        if(b&1)
            d += c;
        if(b>>1){
            b = b>>1;
            c *= c;
        }
    }

    std::cout<<d;
    return 0;
}
```

I suspected that the compiler misinterprets the bitwise operator as an overloaded operator, but even if I change the condition in the while loop to

```
if(b/2 > 0){
    b = b/2;
    c *= c;
}
```

it still doesn't work. I have no idea what is going on here. I've tried this code in the terminal, and some online IDEs, but the result is the same.

Comment: If `b` starts with non-zero value, it will never become zero and the loop never terminates. This is a simple logical error, it has nothing whatsoever to do with operator overloading.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik the answer box is below ;)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik but why? 1/2 = 0 in integer division, right? So, it should reach zero.

Comment: The only spot that changes `b` is the assignment `b = b >> 1`. And that is only performed if `b >> 1` is non-zero; you explicitly test for that. Therefore, `b` can never become zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::cin>>a>>b;` is grouped as `(std::cin>>a)>>b;` so be assured that two integers are read.

Your problem is that the program loops if `b` is anything other than 0.

Comment: In integer division, shouldn't it round down? And hence, eventually, reach zero as 1/2 = 0? If I print (int)1/2 , I see the output as 0.

Comment: @Zargles you never assign a 0 to `b`

Comment: @Zargles: Dude, don't argue with reality. Your program loops. See for yourself with a debugger!

Comment: @Caleth Ah, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, you never assign a 0 value to b, so the loop never ends. You can replace the if test with something that does the assignment.

```
if(b >>= 1)
    c *= c;
```

I prefer this to `b = b >> 1` as it is more obvious you mean to assign, and don't mean to compare `b == b >> 1`